# Rewrite Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I struggling to understand this javascript code and would like to rewrite it to python.

```
function rotateRight(e, t) {
    for (var n, i = 0; (t > i); i++) 
        n = (1 & e), e >>= 1, n <<= 31, e += n;
    return e
}
```

My biggest struggle is to understand how is the `e` being influenced by `n`.

Thank you for help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. If you have a question about a *specific part* of the translation process, please post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. We are not going to do all of your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This code does the following:

1. Loop from `i = 0` to `i < t`
2. on every iteration:
3. `n` is the result of the binary operation `AND` between `1` and `e`;
4. `e` equals `e` but moving all bits `1` position to the right;
5. `n` equals `n` but moving all bits `31` positions to the left;
6. `e` equals `e` plus `n`;
7. When the iteration is over (i is greater that t), e is returned.

Comment: Do you know where this is useful?

Comment: I have no idea, I've just told op what his code means.